# Invoke-WebRequest not returning results as expected

Tags: powershell

I am running this code and its not returning the data to my $response variable as I expected.

```
$targetUrl = "https://www.tigerrunresort.com/vacation-rentals-homes-search.asp?txtStartDate=8%2F1%2F2022&txtEndDate=8%2F7%2F2022&categoryid=11317&destinationID=0&communityID=0&amenBedrooms=-1&maxPersons=0&advs=&sort=0&currentPage=1&flexibleDates=0&flexibleDatesThreshold=&searchAmenities=&showOnlySpecials=0"
 
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetUrl
```

In rawcontent I should expect to see the string "Sorry"   which does not show.    What do I need to do to get it to return the values as I would see interactively?

Thanks!

Comment: The "Sorry" message is generated/fetched by a piece of javascript that runs in your browser _after_ the page has loaded, it's not part of the initial response.

Answer (score 2):

You are not seeing it because it is not actually in the response. It is probably created and appended to the DOM by Javascript. Due to the Invoke-WebRequest not executing Javascript, it is never part of the response. If you are looking to orchestrate browsers (which do execute Javascript and offer access to the DOM) maybe you can try taking a look at Selenium (https://www.selenium.dev/)

Comment: I would prefer a solution that is native to powershell.   Any ideas for how I can accomplish this.    I also tried to execute the IE app but the Document comes back as "null"

Comment: My friend at where I used to work b4 retiring runs my script fine on his w10 box.    But when I run on my w11 box the document is returned as null.

Comment: I checked this out now that I understand a bit more of where MS is going with IE.   First thing I noticed is that there seems to be no support for POWERSHELL in the downloads.    Can someone advise and maybe also show an example of a screen scraper app?   Thanks!

Comment: You could perhaps try looking into a selenium wrapper for Powershell. I looked around a bit and found the following project which might be of help, but I have not tested it and I am not aware of its limitations:

https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell

Comment: Thanks for the help!    Tried and failed quickly.    My 5 years removed from retirement in IT has degraded my skills badly.    I loaded the Selenium module in the modules dir and yet Visual Studio Code cannot find it when I try to install or import.   Thoughts??

Comment: Got a little further and now seeing this error.   Anyone have ideas how to fix?

Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}) on port 57884
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
New-Object: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"

Comment: Got even further.   Ideas of why chrome binary cannot be found??
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}) on port 64442
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"

WARNING: Web driver was not created

Answer (score 0):

For lauching a web request you can use for example start-process like this : `start-process microsoft-edge:http://google.com/`

Comment: If I launch MS-Edge how do I scrape the screen values shown on the screen?

Comment: I haven't try anything like this.
But i have found something (in French) where they scrape values on a web site
The URL : https://github.com/apetitjean/LeBonCoin